# JavaScript - Check if a particular key is available in the JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am retrieving JSON from a live streaming data.
For the first call I am getting dataset array with time and value. But in the second JSON dataset array is empty. I want to check if dataset array contains time key.

Retrieved JSON after first call:

```
 {
  "activities-heart-intraday": {
    "dataset": [{
        "time": "00:00:00",
        "value": 91
    }, {
        "time": "00:01:00",
        "value": 92
    }, {
        "time": "00:02:00",
        "value": 92
    }],
    "datasetInterval": 1,
    "datasetType": "second"
  }
}
```

Retrieved JSON after second call:

```
{
  "activities-heart-intraday": {
    "dataset": [],
    "datasetInterval": 1,
    "datasetType": "second"
  }
}
```

I am doing

```
var value = JSON.parse(data);

if (value.hasOwnProperty('time')) {
   console.log("here");
}
```

to check if time key exists in the JSON, but it's not working.

How can I check if a particular key exists in the array in json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you have to check that `dataset` is not an empty array. Then check that `time` is defined.

This can be solved with:

```
if (dataset[0] !== undefined && dataset[0].time !== undefined)
```

or just:

```
if (dataset[0] && dataset[0].time)
```

If you want to iterate through the array:

```
dataset.forEach(function (data) {
   if (data.time) {
       // your code
   } 
});
```

Comment: alternatively, `dataset.length && dataset.every((obj) => obj.hasOwnProperty('time'))`

Comment: my JSON response is in var data. When I try `if(data. activitiesHeartIntraday.dataset[0] !== undefined && data. activitiesHeartIntraday.dataset[0].time !== undefined` ,
 it gives me error as: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataset' of undefined`

Comment: [Because of the dashes in the key, you have to use the bracket notation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4968448/652669): `data['activities-heart-intraday'].dataset`.

Answer (score 0):

the data has a dataset array so we need to first check if the array is there and then if one of the arrays members has the time property

```
if( data.hasOwnProperty('dataset') && data.dataset.length != 0){    
  if( data.dataset[0].hasOwnProperty('time')){
    console.log('true');    
  }
}
```

Comment: you also need to make sure that `data.dataset` has at least one element

Answer (score 0):

Since in JS you can not natively set and access object properties those with a "`-`" character in it by dot notation you have define them as strings and use bracket notation instead to set and access them. So you can make a check like this

```
data["activities-heart-intraday"].dataset.length > 0 && data["activities-heart-intraday"].dataset.every(e => !!e.time);
```

Comment: it gives me error of `TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataset' of undefined`.
I am checking if `data !== undefined`  before checking dataset. Thanks

Comment: @akshay talathi You should name the main object as `data` first or if it has a different name other than `data` then use that name in the place of `data` in the above conditional.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell what `data` from your question is supposed to be but if it is the whole JSON object, then the most simple way is this:

```
if(data["activities-heart-intraday"]["dataset"][0]["time"])
  console.log('time is set)
```

But beware! If for example the `dataset` is not set, you'll get an error that you are trying to get `time` key from `undefined` and the code will crash. I'd recommend using simple recursive function like this:

```
function is_there_the_key(json, keys){
  if(keys.length == 0)
    return true           //we used the whole array, and every key was found
  let key = keys.shift()  //pop(get and remove) the first string from keys
  if(!json[key]){
    console.log(key + ' not found')
    return false          //one of the keys doesn't exist there
  }
  return is_there_the_key(json[key], keys)
}
```

Whether you return `true` or `false`, both of them will make their way up to the surface.

As the `json` parameter you pass the json you want to search in.

As the `keys` parameter you pass an array (mostly strings) of the keys in order they should go.
For example:

```
if(is_there_the_key(data, ["activities-heart-intraday", "dataset", 0, "time"])
  //we found the key, do something here
```